# Getting an IllegalArgumentException trying to implement ExtendedProperties for android-calendar

Tags: java, eclipse, android-calendar

I am trying to create ExtendedProperties for my event and got this error below :

```
02-06 09:43:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(9530): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[AsyncQueryServiceHelper]
02-06 09:43:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(9530): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only sync adapters may write using content://com.android.calendar/extendedproperties
02-06 09:43:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
02-06 09:43:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithOperationApplicationExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:160)
02-06 09:43:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.applyBatch(ContentProviderNative.java:484)
02-06 09:43:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:227)
02-06 09:43:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:954)
02-06 09:43:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at com.android.calendar.iselection.AsyncQueryServiceHelper.onHandleIntent(AsyncQueryServiceHelper.java:327)
02-06 09:43:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
02-06 09:43:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 09:43:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
02-06 09:43:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

My code below :

```
ContentValues customerContentValues = new ContentValues();
Uri uriExtendedProperties = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/extendedproperties");
customerContentValues.put(Events._ID,model.mId);
customerContentValues.put("ClientIdname", model.mCustomerName);
customerContentValues.put("RdvType", model.mEventType);
customerContentValues.put("RdvEmplacement", model.mEmplacement);
customerContentValues.put("RdvAdresse", model.mAddresse);
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(uriExtendedProperties).withValues(customerContentValues).build());
```

Is there anything i've missed ? need some push.. thanks in advance

Is there somebody to tell more about sync adapter beacause i'm really stucked.... any suggestion will be welcomed.

Comment: change your title its totally un-orderd

Comment: @BhargavModi, is this correct???

Answer (score 1):

`ExtendedProperties` is a little different then the ordinary `Evnets` and `Attendees` tables.

in order to write to it you will need to modify the uri you are using and adding '***caller_is_syncadapter***', '***account_name***' and '***account_type***' params.

here is an example:

```
Uri extendedPropUri = ExtendedProperties.CONTENT_URI;
    extendedPropUri = extendedPropUri.buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER,"true")
            .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, this.accountName)
            .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, this.accountType).build();
```

and then the insert looks like:

```
ContentValues extraDataValues = new ContentValues();
extraDataValues.put(ExtendedProperties.EVENT_ID, eventId);
extraDataValues.put(ExtendedProperties.NAME, key);
extraDataValues.put(ExtendedProperties.VALUE, value);

context.getContentResolver().insert(extendedPropUri, extraDataValues);
```